# How to change TCP Congestion Control algorithm using setsockopt() call from C++ code

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp, setsockopt, congestion-control

Is it possible to change [TCP congestion control algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_congestion_control) from `Cubic` to `Reno` or vice versa using [setsockopt](https://linux.die.net/man/2/setsockopt) call **from C++ code** in linux?
I am looking for an example code of doing so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [`TCP_CONGESTION`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/tcp.7.html) socket option to get or set the congestion control algorithm for a socket to one of the values listed in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_allowed_congestion_control` or to any one of the values in `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_available_congestion_control` if your process is privileged.

C example:

```c
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netinet/tcp.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char buf[256];
    socklen_t len;
    int sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    if (sock == -1)
    {
        perror("socket");
        return -1;
    }

    len = sizeof(buf);

    if (getsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_CONGESTION, buf, &len) != 0)
    {
        perror("getsockopt");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Current: %s\n", buf);

    strcpy(buf, "reno");

    len = strlen(buf);

    if (setsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_CONGESTION, buf, len) != 0)
    {
        perror("setsockopt");
        return -1;
    }

    len = sizeof(buf);

    if (getsockopt(sock, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_CONGESTION, buf, &len) != 0)
    {
        perror("getsockopt");
        return -1;
    }

    printf("New: %s\n", buf);

    close(sock);
    return 0;
}
```

For me outputs:

```
Current: cubic
New: reno
```

Comment: But, how can I change it using `setsockopt` call from C++ code? That is my question as well. I know that it can be changed command line as well provided that privileges are present.

Comment: @Game_Of_Threads: I've added a small example in C to illustrate. I can add some comments if it isn't self explanatory.